# return a file async in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to run a cpu/data intensive method to return a file asynchronously, but it runs synchronously. I would like the user to be able to continue using the site while the file is processing. Is this achievable? This is what I have that works, but synchronously:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetSignUpReportForCsv(ReportFilterInput input)
    {
        reportDb = new ReportDb(DbSession, CommunityRouteInfo);
        var model = new SignupReportView();
        try
        {
            model = await reportDb.GetSignUpReportForCsv(input);
            return File(model.FileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, model.Filename);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        TempData["Message"] = "The file is being processed and the save dialog will appear when it is ready";
        return RedirectToAction("ReportingHome", "Report");
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work this way, you probably confuse the meaning of async in this case. In order to achieve this user experience, you need to return a page and then load the report using AJAX.

Comment: *"I would like the user to be able to continue using the site while the file is processing."* - I think you're misinterpreting "async" in this case, and as a result what you're asking is really broad.  If you want the user to continue to use the site while a background process happens, then that process needs to be in the background.  The controller action would do nothing more than schedule the process, perhaps by writing a record to a database or a message queue.  Another process (windows service? console app? etc.) would check for new records and process them offline.

Comment: You should remove that empty catch block. Those hide errors in your application and are almost never a good idea.

Comment: Maybe are you talking about the "download" attribute for an anchor in HTML ?

Comment: Continuing on from David's idea, once that other processes has finished generating your file, you would then need a way to present it to the user for download. This could be as simple as having some JavaScript poll the web server to check if new downloads are ready. Or your background process can notify the web server directly (perhaps using SignalR) which would then notify the client's browser a new download is ready (a push notification).

Comment: Don't know why i didn't think of AJAX, thanks Yeldar